# run a workflow when a new item is added

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

we require a workflow which should run when a new item is added to the form library(infopath)  and should update the value of a field "title" with the filename(eg:111.xml).

Please let us know, how we can accomplish it.
I am authorized to use SharePoint designer tool. But not sure,how i will...

Comment: Please add more information on what you have tried so far. And which part of the workflow you have problems with. It can also help to link to the tutorials you have tried so far and which part of those you are having issues with.

Comment: I have commented on @erik 's below post, which states why we am looking for a workflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a basic forms library and create and publish a simple InfoPath form to that forms library, you'll notice that when you create a new form (via add document) and save it, SharePoint will automatically populate the out-of-the-box Title field with the name of the form (111.xml).  You should change the library's default view to show you the Title so you can see the behavior.

However, renaming the form via Edit Properties will not update the Title field with the new name of the form (222.xml). This is where you would need a workflow.

In SharePoint Designer add a new workflow with a single "Set Field in Current Item" Action. Then configure "Set field" to "Title" and "value" to "[%Current Item:Name%].xml" using the Lookup button in the String Builder dialog. Lastly make sure you check the "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed" in the Workflow Settings and publish your workflow to the library.

Your Title field will now always be up-to-date.  The only caveat is that you may need to refresh the view after your updates because the workflow may not be completed before the browser finished rendering the view/page.

Comment: what you said is correct....the title field will be populated with the file name(111.xml) in default when a new item is added. In our case what is happening is that, after the migration to Windows 7 from XP, this is not occurring.ie, the title field is not populating in default when a new item is added. I tried searching all over the internet, but i didn't found any valuable info to fix it.That's why I think of writing a workflow to accomplish it. If any others, please let me know.....

Comment: I'm assuming that you are filling out the InfoPath form in the web browser and saving it there -- not using the full InfoPath client.  Since I'm referring to the web based version and all that is required would be a browser, the OS should not matter.

Comment: We are on client based. Windows 7 64bit with MS Office 2010 32bit(i guess) , hope that helps. Please let me know if what you said is not applicable for both the cases(automatically save title field).

Comment: Sounds to me like your issue is coming from the InfoPath client. You may want to try a 32-bit version of Windows 7 with the 32-bit InfoPath client and also a 64-bit OS with 64-bit office.

Comment: yet to check whether that's the issue, will check now and post an update on it. Did Internet explorer 32/64 bit will have a direct impact on it?...

Comment: I just checked with a 64-bit OS and 32-bit InfoPath client and the full client behaves differently compared to the web-based InfoPath form.  The full client does *not* save the Title value.

Comment: could you please check and update whether its working fine in 32 bit environments or in  64 bit environments. For us it may take upto 1 week to make the s/w installation by the support team... I will be glad if you please check this also. Prior to the migration to Win 7 everything was fine on the client based forms.Not sure where is the issue.